# Image Classification using Tensorflow Serving and What If Tool

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-serving

I am pretty new to tensorflow, Machine Learning and Stackoverflow as well. So please bear with me as your critique will be welcome.

My goal is to analyze different models in the What-If Tool (WIT) to understand classification decisions. It works well with something like the UCI census Tutorial, however when images are involved WIT refuses it's service in Tensorflow-Serving as well as in a Notebook (tested both with the [WIT smile detector](https://github.com/PAIR-code/what-if-tool/blob/master/WIT_Smile_Detector.ipynb)) without reporting issues.

So I thought, maybe my machine isn't powerfull enough and tried the smaller MNIST dataset as reference, which did not work either, but gave me error messages:

inference address localhost:8500

> "Model inference failed: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE details = "failed to connect to all addresses" debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1626855633.284000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":5391,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1626855633.284000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}" >"

inference address localhost:8501

> "Model inference failed: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE details = "failed to connect to all addresses" debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1626855671.426000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":5391,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1626855671.426000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}" >"

inference address localhost:8500,localhost:8501

> "Model inference failed:"

The serving of the model is handled with a Tensorflow-Serving Docker (ports published 8500 and 8501 mapped to its respective local counterparts) container and tensorboard is running either from the local machine or developement Tensorflow Docker Container.

My system setup is Windows 10, working in a Tensorflow Docker container (Tensorflow 2.5.0, python 3.6.9, published ports 8888, 6006 to its respective local counterparts) and Visual Studio Code.

The code can be found on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Hi5tUgjoQj7-3tDCW8AH8rHpxI1jDOlA?usp=sharing)

I imported MNIST on purpose as images in jpg and labels as csv since it should mimic the data I want to analyse in WIT down the road.

Comment: I tried reproducing your code and I am getting a different error like FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Processed/labels/test.csv' Can you take a look at your colab and correct me if I am missing anything. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowSupport thanks for the response. I almost forgot about this issue and am on a different matter at the moment. If I get back to my original problem I will update here.